# How state works when value changes?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I use a very simple example to check my understanding of how state works. Below is a simple calculator with initial value 1.

When I press the button +, the console shows "Run" and the calculator shows "2".
When I press the button + again, the console still outputs "Run" and the calculator shows "2".
When I continue to press +, console does not output anything.

```
import {useState} from "react";

const App = () => {

    console.log("Run")

    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(1);

    console.log(counter)

    const addHandler = () => {
        setCounter(2);
    };
    const subtractHandler = () => {
        setCounter(counter - 1);
    };
    return <div className="app">
        <h1>{counter}</h1>
        <button onClick={addHandler}>+</button>
        <button onClick={subtractHandler}>-</button>
    </div>
  };

export default App;
```

The second output is confusing me, because my understanding is that state will re-render the function when the state variable "counter" changes. However, after the first press, the counter is already set to be "2". When the button + was pressed one more time, why console still outputs "Run" and "2"?

Comment: "my understanding is that state will re-render the function" no, React will re-render the component and a state change is one of the possible reasons for that. afaik. React doesn't provide you with any information on what exactly triggered a particular re-render so don't overthink this.

Answer (score 0):

Your `addHandler` assigned to your buttons `onClick` event is not incrementing your `counter` value but rather always assigning the value `2`.

```
const addHandler = () => {
    setCounter(2);  // always setting the value of counter to 2
}
```

What you likely want is to access the previous state value of `counter` and increment its value:

```
const addHandler = () => {
    setCounter(value => value + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use  console.log("Run") inside the addHanlder function,in this way console log will work on every time the addHandler function will be called and set the counter state like this:

```js
const addHandler = () => {
  console.log("Run")
  setCounter(counter + 1);
};
```